# Gps tracking google maps

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, google-api

I am developing an application which requires a tracking service. The app stores coordinates to a database IF the user has travelled x meters since the last stored position..

I am using phonegaps geolocation service to get locations etc..

Problem is that the gps isnt precise, if I sit in my chair and check the position, if can differ a couple of meters now and then, resulting in a cluttered track..

Does anyone have a solution for this? 
-I am thinking of an algorhitm that checks the acceleration, and prevents the device from storing a location if the acceleration increases to much/suddenly.

Would that be a good approach, or have anyone had a similar problem before?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the device acceleration is not an ideal starting point, since it does not necessarily correlate in any form with the person changing his/her location, but I can't offer any solution. GPS can be imprecise sometimes. Two following geolocations can sometimes differ 50 meters without actually having moved. At least that's what I was experiencing. Maybe triggering a series of geolocation events for each location check would help, but that would suck performance wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer if anyone still is interested.

Android devices "jump" to near antennas every now and then (at least the ones we tried on), and when they do position.coords.speed is set to null. All we needed to do was to prevent storing positions if speed == null.. =)